# Join Two Non Related Tables

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables Like A and B. Each have one column (ID) in **ascending order**.
I want to join tables LIKE C Table. Datas are not statical but in A and B the row counts are always equal. I've tried join statements but couldn't find out. Thanks for your help.

```
A (ID)
--
2
3
4
6
8

B (ID)
--
11
12
13
14
15

C ( IDA ,  IDB )
--
2     11
3     12
4     13
6     14
8     15
```

Comment: 1. Use `ROW_NUMBER` to give an unique id for every row 2. Use `FULL OUTER JOIN` (or `INNER JOIN` if you can guarantee they always have the same number of rows) to join them by that row number value

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: In my view, if the tables are not related, this is not something that should be handled in the database. It should be handled in the client code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a database that supports row_number() such as Oracle, postgresql, sql sql server:

```
select a_id, b_id
  from (select row_number() over(order by id) as a_rn, id as a_id from a) x
  join (select row_number() over(order by id) as b_rn, id as b_id from b) y
    on x.a_rn = y.b_rn
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5ac6b/1/0

If you're using mysql you can mimic row_number using a variable:

```
select a_id, b_id
  from (select @rn := @rn + 1 as a_rn, id as a_id
          from a
         cross join (select @rn := 0) r) x
  join (select @rx := @rx + 1 as b_rn, id as b_id
          from b
         cross join (select @rx := 0) r) y
    on x.a_rn = y.b_rn
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ac6b/2/0

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select a.id ida,b.id idb from 
( select a.*, row_number() over (order by id) rn from a) a
join (select b.*, row_number() over (order by id) rn from b) b on a.rn=b.rn
```

Answer (score 0):

**Joining Non-Related Tables**

[image]

***Demo SQL Script***

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#T1') IS NOT NULL  DROP TABLE #T1;

CREATE TABLE #T1 (T1_Name VARCHAR(75));

INSERT INTO #T1 (T1_Name) VALUES ('Animal'),('Bat'),('Cat'),('Duet');

SELECT * FROM #T1;

IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#T2') IS NOT NULL  DROP TABLE #T2;

CREATE TABLE #T2 (T2_Class VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO #T2 (T2_Class) VALUES ('Z'),('T'),('H'); 

SELECT * FROM #T2;
```

To Join Non-Related Tables , we are going to introduce one common joining column of Serial Numbers like below.

**SQL Script**

```
SELECT T1.T1_Name,ISNULL(T2.T2_Class,'') AS T2_Class FROM
( SELECT T1_Name,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS S_NO FROM #T1) T1
LEFT JOIN
( SELECT T2_Class,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS S_NO FROM #T2) T2
ON t1.S_NO=T2.S_NO;
```